# Centering RelativePanels in UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, relativepanel

I'm trying to set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Center so that the RelativePanel will be right in the middle of the UWP app. There are children items inside the RelativePanel, and the children are supposed to be centered **inside** the RelativePanel. It's supposed to look like:[image]As you can see, the RelativePanel is in the middle, and the children are **on top of each other** and **centered**. I tried this XAML code:

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="relativePanel1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="Yo, waddup? Enter your GUID to continue" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" FontFamily="Chiller" FontSize="72" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" InputScope="Text" PlaceholderText="{}{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}" RelativePanel.Below="textBlock1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</RelativePanel>
```

Here's how it looks like when debugging:

[image]Am I doing something wrong in here? I'm using a RelativePanel instead of a StackPanel because I need the two children on top of each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"` to your `TextBlock` and `TextBox`.

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="relativePanel1"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"
               RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
               Text="Yo, waddup? Enter your GUID to continue"
               IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"
               FontFamily="Chiller"
               FontSize="72" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1"
             RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             InputScope="Text"
             PlaceholderText="{}{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
             RelativePanel.Below="textBlock1" />
</RelativePanel>
```

There might be more than this though. Your `RelativePanel` clearly looks *top-aligned* to me. That means its parent panel is not *stretched*. Also, you don't have to use a `RelativePanel` here if centering is all it does. You can replace it with a `StackPanel` and manually set `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` on all its children.

Comment: Thanks! It totally worked. Could you tell me what I did wrong in my previous code?

Comment: Yeah you basically need to use `RelativePanel.xxx` on your elements to position them accordingly. Have a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel).